# If a Twilio number is handled with a SIP trunk, is it possible to add other handling?

Tags: twilio, sip, hubspot-api

I have a Twilio number that, when it receives a call, uses a SIP trunk to forward the call to Microsoft Teams. I wanted to use a webhook to trigger a third party action when the call comes in, to log the call to my CRM. It seems that with the SIP trunk I can't use a webhook, or a function, or anything else.

What other option do I have to capture the call log when the call hangs up, given that the call is being handled with a SIP? Are there webhooks for a new call log showing up in Twilio? If so I can't find any documentation. Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

I tried to use a webhook, twilio studio, or a function to set up the third party API call. I was expecting that the phone calls would be handled in one of those ways. I found out that the phone numbers are primarily managed with SIP forwarding to teams.